# Password disappears from ODBC Data Source Administrator

Tags: sql, sql-server, excel, powershell

I created a user data source based on

http://blog.mclaughlinsoftware.com/2012/09/12/sql-server-odbc-osn/

When I try to invoke a powershell script that sends SQL data to EXCEL

```
$qt = $ws.QueryTables.Add("ODBC;DSN=$DSN", $ws.Range("A1"), $SQL)

if ($qt.Refresh()){
    $ws.Activate()
    $ws.Select()
}
```

The EXCEL spreadsheet appears and prompts me for the SAME password that I entered when creating the DSN

[image]

And when I go to ODBC Data Source Administrator, select the DSN I created, click "Configure", and keep going "Next", it shows password field is blank

[image]

How to I fix this so
1. Password remains in DSN
2. I am not prompted for password everytime I run Powershell script that sends SQL data to EXCEL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify the user id and password in the application connection in order to avoid the prompt.  The SQL Server ODBC drivers do not store user credentials.  I believe you can just specify the credentials in the connection string:

```
$qt = $ws.QueryTables.Add("ODBC;DSN=$DSN;UID=YourLogin;PWD=YourLoginPassword", $ws.Range("A1"), $SQL)
```

Note that you should never use the `sa` login for routine application data access.

Comment: I used credential other than 'sa' now